# Open multiple files based on conditionals using a single with statement

Tags: python, file, io, conditional-statements, with-statement

I want to open multiple files using a `with` statement (so I get the benefit of the context manager) based on boolean flags which instruct whether my program should or should not actually open each file.

I know I can use a `with` statement to open multiple files, like:

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as logfile, open('out_a.txt', 'w') as out_a, open('out_b.txt', 'w') as out_b:
    # do something with logfile, out_a and out_b
# all files are closed here
```

I want to run a similar statement, but **only opening certain files based on their corresponding flags**. I thought about implementing it as a `conditional_open`function, something like:

```
write_log = True
write_out_a = False
write_out_b = True

with conditional_open('log.txt', 'w', cond=write_log) as logfile, open('out_a.txt', 'w', cond=write_out_a) as out_a, open('out_b.txt', 'w', cond=write_out_b) as out_b:
    # do something with logfile, out_a and out_b
# all files are closed here
```

But I'm a little confused as to how properly create that function. Ideally, `coditional_open` would either return an open file handle or `None` (in which case the file is never created/touched/deleted):

```
def conditional_open(filename, mode, cond):
    return open(filename, mode) if cond else None
```

But I fear that this skips the benefits of the context manager when opening a file, since I'm calling `open` outside from it. Is this assumption correct?

Can anyone give some ideas about how I could be doing this? I know I could create mock file objects based on the conditions and write to them instead, but it sounds a bit too convoluted to me - this seems like a simple problem, which *should* have a simple solution in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up your function as a context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def conditional_open(f_name, mode, cond):
    if not cond:
        yield None
    resource = open(f_name, mode)
    try:
        yield resource
    finally:
        resource.close()
```